# TowelRoot v3 User Interface Anomaly

Tags: rooting, root-access, security, user-interface

I downloaded the latest TowelRoot (v3) from the official website and I noticed a UI anomaly and wanted to know if anyone else has experienced this. Most screenshots of the "make it ra1n" screen (from other peoples' phones in tutorials) are complete, however on my tablet the last part of the "n" was cut off making it appear to be "make it ra1r". (Screenshot 1)

[image]

After switching to portrait I was a little more assured when I could see it was just cut off. (Screenshot 2)

[image]

I want to know if this was a known problem or a mistake by someone trying to reissue a counterfeit. I've looked at the whois domain registration and it appears to be under the control of the same owner since 2014. (Screenshot 3 and 4)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I downloaded the same TowelRoot APK from the same source, and for me the string `make it ra1n` is perfectly visible. Might it be an issue with your system font?

Comment: Yeah, that changes things. It's strange though: Tiny, Extra Small, Medium and Huge render normal, but Small, Large, Extra Large don't. Just for future reference and out of curiosity: Would something like this be device specific? Does yours render incorrectly when you change the font size?

Comment: No, I changed the font size to 85% and 130% of its usual size, and I spotted no difference outside TowelRoot's title breaking in two lines with the 130% font size. If I recall correctly from my past experience, though, if no sufficient care is put when creating the single glyphs that compose a font, this behaviour is certain to occur. It is caused by either a concentration or lack of pixels in a given area, and it is indeed experienced when stretching the font size. Not a sign of font quality.